# Set var to null on assignment if jQuery object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to make a jQuery object evaluate to false **when it's created** if its length is 0?

Here's what I'd like to be able to do:

```
var Constructor = function (config) {

  this.obj = $(config.id) || null;

};
```

But that doesn't work -- if `config.id` is not passed or `#id` is not found, `this.obj` becomes an empty jQuery object that evaluates to true.

What I want is for `this.obj` to be `null` on creation (or to be a populated jQuery object if the arg/id exists) and to **avoid having to check the length** of the resulting jQuery object.

Comment: You could check against the `length` property of the object

Comment: this.obj = $(config.id).get(0) may do it, it gets the Javascript object from the jQuery object

Comment: I think there is only one way to check if element exist by checking length of its array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `.length` test up in a jQuery function:

```
$.fn.nonEmpty = function() {
  return this.length && this;
};
```

Then:

```
this.obj = $(config.id).nonEmpty() || null;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `this.obj` have a value of `true` if it's not empty?

Comment: @cantera no, because the JavaScript `&&` operator returns the first non-false value *without converting it to boolean*.  Thus, the return value will be either `0` or a non-empty jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks - I consider this the cleanest approach shown so far.

Comment: Sorry that comment above explains thing incorrectly; `&&` returns its first operand (left side) if that value is "falsy", and the second operand (right side) otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying -- this is a very useful technique.

Answer (score 2):

Just use its `.length` property:

```
var Constructor = function (config) {
  var elem = $(config.id);
  this.obj = elem.length ? elem : null;
};
```

Since jQuery returns an empty array if nothing is found, its length will be `0` which evaluates to `false`

If you want to avoid length lookup, you can do this:

```
var Constructor = function (config) {
  var elem = $(config.id);
  this.obj = elem[0] ? elem : null;
};
```

Comment: Updated my question -- I should have specified that checking the length in a separate step is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Wasn't me - I'm only seeing the +2

Comment: @cantera I know who it is and I also know it wasn't you :) It has been reverted back though

Answer (score 0):

To make check if id is passed - you can use:

```
var Constructor = function (config) {

  this.obj = $(config.id || null );

};
```

But because of $ returns a collection - you should check length of this collection by `.length`

```
var Constructor = function (config) {    
  var $collection = $(config.id);

  this.obj = $collection.length ? $collection : null;
};
```

Comment: I suppose he wanted `this.obj` to be `null`. Your code returns `[]` which is not what OP wants I suppose

Comment: Good idea, but that produces the same result. If I evaluate `this.obj`, it still returns true even if `null` is being wrapped.

Comment: @AmitJoki: Yes that's correct, I'd like `this.obj` to take the value `null`.

Comment: @cantera check out my answer then. It does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, another short solution is this:

```
var check = $(config.id);
this.obj = check.get(0)==null ? null : check
```

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/V3G6U/2/

Comment: Thanks - I like the syntax, but unfortunately it requires diving into the DOM twice to find the element.

Comment: Fixed, its a 2 liner now ;p.